# Discord.js Backdoor command

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I've seen my bot join many more servers, but it seems like some are abusing it.

I want the bot to make a one time use invite to a server that I am not on, but my bot is. Once I am on the server I can just remove it. It would be like so:

^backdoor "guild id". I am very new to coding. Thanks!

Comment: You need a channel to create an invite, so guild.channels.first().createInvite() with some tweaking should be good https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=createInvite

Comment: so Ive tried client.guilds.get('474317783740579872').guild.channels.first().createInvite()
it hasnt worked. Anything else?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 possible ways of doing this, but both are reliant on the permissions that the bot has in that guild.

guildid has to be replaced with an ID or an variable equivilant to the ID

- Way 1:

  ```
  let guild = client.guilds.get(guildid):
  if (!guild) return message.reply("The bot isn't in the guild with this ID.");

  guild.fetchInvites()
      .then(invites => message.channel.send('Found Invites:\n' + invites.map(invite => invite.code).join('\n')))
      .catch(console.error);
  ```
- Way 2:

  ```
  let guild = client.guilds.get(guildid):
  if (!guild) return message.reply("The bot isn't in the guild with this ID.");

  let invitechannels = guild.channels.filter(c=> c.permissionsFor(guild.me).has('CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE'))
  if(!invitechannels) return message.channel.send('No Channels found with permissions to create Invite in!')

  invitechannels.random().createInvite()
     .then(invite=> message.channel.send('Found Invite:\n' + invite.code))
  ```

There would also be the way of filtering the channels for SEND_MESSAGE and you could send a message to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of entering the guild and then removing it, it would be simpler to just make the bot leave the guild, using [`Guild.leave()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=leave)

```js
// ASSUMPTIONS:
// guild_id is the argument from the command
// message is the message that triggered the command

// place this inside your command check
let guild = client.guilds.get(guild_id);
if (!guild) return message.reply("The bot isn't in the guild with this ID.");

guild.owner.send("The bot has been removed from your guild by the owner.").then(() => {
  guild.leave();
});
```

Comment: Well i kind of wanted to have a one on one talk with the owner, but thank you so much.

Comment: Oh, ok. The problem is that you need permissions to create invites, and many servers deny that permission to bots, so there's no consistent way of doing what you want :\

Comment: Ive tried using it on my own sever where the bot has perms, still no idea how